# Is it possible to get a multiple-entry visa for Cambodia before arrival?

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, cambodia

I'm traveling to Laos via Cambodia on an Australian passport. I'm going to have to change airlines in Siem Reap Airport, so I will (presumably) need to clear immigration, claim my bag and check-in again. However, on the way back we're going to be spending a few days in Siem Reap.

Cambodia's e-Visa and Visa on Arrival options all appear to be single-entry, and I can't find any information on obtaining a multiple-entry visa beyond some suggestions it can be obtained in Cambodia itself - something that we're not going to be able to do on a stopover.

Is it possible to obtain a multiple-entry visa for Cambodia before arrival, or will I have to get two single-entry visas just days apart?

Comment: Negative voter: I'm open to suggestions as to what to improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge Cambodia tourist visas and eVisas are single-entry only.

But it is possible to transit in Siem Reap without entering the country, assuming you can have your bags checked through to Laos. Are you flying on the same airline or are you changing airlines?

Comment: I'm going to have to change airlines in Siem Reap Airport (Singapore to Vietnam) and they're on separate tickets as well, so I'm 99% sure I can't check my bags through.

Comment: Singapore and Vietnam do have interline agreements.  While they primarily apply to single ticket bookings, you might try asking Singapore first before applying for two visas.